# Explicitly specifying locations for symbols in ld

Tags: c, gcc, ld

Let's assume that I have the following C code:

```
extern int f_1();
extern int g_1();

extern int f_2();
extern int g_2();

extern int f_3();
extern int g_3();

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Using f_1, f_2, f_3 and g_1, g_2, g_3 here:
    ...
}
```

And I want to build it by linking with 3 different libraries: `l1`, `l2`, `l3` -- assuming each of them exports its own `f` and `g` functions -- so that:

- `f_1` and `g_1` will be resolved to `f` and `g` respectively from `l1`;
- `f_2` and `g_2` will be resolved to `f` and `g` respectively from `l2`;
- `f_3` and `g_3` will be resolved to `f` and `g` respectively from `l3`.

Is this possible with gcc and ld:

1. Is this possible if `l1`, `l2`, `l3` are shared libraries (**.so**)?
2. Is this possible if `l1`, `l2`, `l3` are archives (**.a**)?

Comment: It should be possible with shared libraries (.so) files IMO. Maybe [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) will help.

Answer (score 1):

[objcopy](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/objcopy.html)'s `--redefine-sym` option is your friend:

> --redefine-sym *old*=*new*
>
> Change the name of a symbol *old*, to *new*. This can be useful when one is
>   trying link two things together for which you have no source, and there are
>   name collisions.
>
> --redefine-syms=*filename*
>
> Apply --redefine-sym to each symbol pair "*old* *new*" listed in the file
>   *filename*. *filename* is simply a flat file, with one symbol pair per line.
>   Line comments may be introduced by the hash character. This option may be
>   given more than once.

Apply it to you libraries `l1`, `l2`, `l3`. It should work both for **.a** and **.so**.

Comment: This is only for **.o** files, isn't it? And it **modifies** (or *creates copy of*) an object file -- so not a way to link to existing .so/.a files, am I right?

Comment: That's a reasonable suggestion, but the question was "Is this possible with gcc and ld [...]?".  Shall I take your answer as a "no" to that?

Comment: The danger is that the libraries may still have given the same name to different objects and functions. And `objcopy` change the visibility of public symbols to be hidden, except for the specific functions that the OP wants to rename?

Comment: @Sasha objcopy handles **.a** and **.so** files too. It can both modify the input file or create a renamed copy.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I would say that in general case, the answer to OP's original question is "no".

Comment: @Leon, but it forces me to clone .a/.so file -- not allowing to link directly to existing one. Am I right? (Although, with .a files it probably makes no difference whether I link to original .a or modified.)

Comment: @Sasha You got it right. But look out for other possible conflicts between other symbols in the libraries.

Comment: @Leon, and if it need to link *identically-named* functions from *different* .so files (without modifying or copying them) -- really no way to do that without [dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)?

Comment: Are they different functions, that happen to have identical names? If so - should both of them be callable?

Comment: @Sasha That will be a problem. Even dlopen will not help (if the two functions need to be usable at the same time).

Comment: @Leon, dlopen will surely help. But I don't believe that pure ld cannot do it (it's such a trivial task).